# Show that $E_{t}=\left( \mathbf{x}_{t},\mathbf{E}_{1},\mathbf{E}_{2},\mathbf{E}_{3}\right)$ is a first order frame field along $\mathbf{x}_{t}$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

> Show that about any $m_{0}\in U$, there exist a neighborhood $V\subset U$
>   and a positive number $\delta \leq \epsilon $ for which there exist smooth
>   vector fields
>   $$
> \mathbf{E}_{a}:V\times \left( -\delta ,\delta \right) \rightarrow 
> \mathbb{R}^3,
> $$
>   for $a=1,2,3$, such that $E_{t}=\left( \mathbf{x}_{t},\mathbf{E}_{1},\mathbf{%
> E}_{2},\mathbf{E}_{3}\right) :V\rightarrow E\left( 3\right) $ is a first
>   order frame field along $x_{t}$ for each $t\in \left( -\delta ,\delta
> \right) $, with the property that
>   $$
> \mathbf{E}_{1}\left( m,0\right) =\mathbf{e}_{1}\left( m\right) \text{, }%
> \mathbf{E}_{2}\left( m,0\right) =\mathbf{e}_{21}\left( m\right) \text{, }%
> \mathbf{E}_{3}\left( m,0\right) =\mathbf{e}_{3}\left( m\right) 
> $$
>   for every $m\in V$. Consequently,
>   $$
> \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}_{j}}{\partial t}\left( m,0\right) \cdot \mathbf{e}%
> _{j}\left( m\right)
> = \left. \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial }{\partial t} \right|_{t=0}\left( \mathbf{E}_{j}\cdot \mathbf{E}_{j}\right)
> =0
> $$
>   for every $m\in V$ for $j=1,2$.

I only managed to show the existence of the fields, but I could not show the rest, that is, first order frame field and the others ...

We are using the definition below

> **Definition 8.1.**
>   An *admissible variation* of $\mathbf{x}$ is any smooth map
>   $$
>          X
>   \colon M \times (-\epsilon, \epsilon)
>   \to    \mathbb{R}^3,
> $$
>   with compact *support*, such that for each $t \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, the map
>   $$
>          \mathbf{x}_t
>   \colon M
>   \to    \mathbb{R}^3,
>   \quad  \mathbf{x}_t(m)
>   =      X(m,t),
> $$
>   is an immersion.
>   The support of $X$ is the closure in $M$ of the set of points of $M$ where $\mathbf{x}_t(m) \neq \mathbf{x}(m)$, for some $t$.

and

> **Definition 3.5**
>   A *first order frame field along $\mathbf{x}$* is a frame field $e \colon U \to G$ along $\mathbf{x}$ for which
>   $$
>     e^* \omega^{m+1}
>   = \dotsb
>   = e^* \omega^n
>   = 0,
>   \quad
>   e^* \omega^1 \wedge \dotsb \wedge e^* \omega^m \neq 0.
> $$
>   at every point of $U$.
>
> (Original scanned image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNi5F.png).)